# Why was such an unrevealing title originally chosen for the movie "The Assignment", and then changed for some International markets to "Tomboy"?

Tags: title, distribution, the-assignment

The low budget Michelle Rodriguez movie [The Assignment](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5034474/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) involves a plot where a killer is punished by a mad surgeon by being given a male to female sex change.

It is not a great movie and was not well received critically (but no movie with Sigourney Weaver can be *that* bad, surely).

But the original title "The Assignment" gives seems bland to the point of anonymity and gives nothing away about the bizarre plot. But this was changed for some international markets (like the UK) to "Tomboy" which at least hints at the key element of the plot.

Why was such a bland title originally chosen and why was it changed for international release?

Comment: Sounds like it was meant to be a clever play on gender *assignment* surgery.